# Solve for closed form $a_j$ given $a_j = 1 + pa_{j+1} + (1-p)a_{j-1}$ where $a_1 = 0$.

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion, random-walk

> Solve for a closed form expression for $a_j$ given constant $p \in (0,1)$ and $q=1-p$ and:
> \begin{align*}
>   a_j &= 1 + pa_{j+1} + qa_{j-1} \\
> \end{align*}
> Given that $a_1 = 0$.

The text says to use the hint that $a_j = c(1-j)$, but where do we get that hint? If we plug in that hint, we get $a_j = \frac{1-j}{p-q} = \frac{1-j}{2p-1}$ which correctly satisfies the original equation. But how would I solve this without the given hint?

Is this matrix version of the original equation helpful in any way?

\begin{align*}
  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -\frac{1}{p} & \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) & \frac{1}{p} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ a_{j-1} \\ a_j \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ a_j \\ a_{j+1} \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: It's a second degree recurrence equation, so you need to know $a_1$ and $a_2$ to determine all the $a_j$, see my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition of the hint is that from state $j$ you need to "move to the left" a net total of $j-1$ times to reach the absorbing state $1$, and the expected number of steps to move one unit to the left is independent of $j$ because the transition probabilities are.

For an order-2 recurrence relation, you should be given two initial conditions, so I assume $a_2=1/(1-2p)$ in addition to $a_1=0$.

Without being given or recognizing the hint, one approach is to use generating functions.  Let $A(z)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j z^j$.  The recurrence relation for $j \ge 2$ implies that
\begin{align}
A(z) - a_1 z^1 
&= \sum_{j=2}^\infty \left(1 + p a_{j+1} + q a_{j-1}\right) z^j \\
&= \sum_{j=2}^\infty z^j + \frac{p}{z} \sum_{j=2}^\infty a_{j+1} z^{j+1} + q z \sum_{j=2}^\infty a_{j-1} z^{j-1} \\
&= \frac{z^2}{1-z} + \frac{p}{z} (A(z) - a_1 z^1 - a_2 z^2) + q z A(z) \\
&= \frac{z^2}{1-z} - p a_2 z + \left(\frac{p}{z} + q z\right) A(z).
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
A(z) &= \frac{z^2/(1-z)-p a_2 z}{1-p/z-qz} \\
&= \frac{z^3-p a_2 z^2(1-z)}{(1-z)(z-p-qz^2)} \\
&= \frac{(1-2p)z^3-p z^2(1-z)}{(1-2p)(1-z)(z-p-(1-p)z^2)} \\
&= \frac{z^2}{(1-2p)(1-z)^2} \\
&= \frac{z^2}{1-2p}\sum_{j=0}\binom{j+1}{1}z^j \\
&= \frac{1}{1-2p}\sum_{j=2}\binom{j-1}{1}z^j,
\end{align}
which implies that $$a_j=\frac{j-1}{1-2p}.$$

Comment: How $a_2$ disappeared  in your calculation of $A(z)$

Comment: I replaced $a_2$ with $1/(1-2p)$ based on a second initial condition.

Comment: Why did you assume $a_2 = 1/(1-2p)$?

Comment: For an order-2 recurrence relation you need two initial conditions.  You had $a_1=0$ but need one more.

Comment: ok, even if you need two initial conditions, how/why did you pick that specific second initial condition?

Comment: Why $a_2$?  Because it comes after $a_1$. Why that value for $a_2$? Because it is the correct value, as you already derived.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_j = a_{j+1} - a_j$, $b_j$ satisfies
$$-pb_{j} + qb_{j-1} = 1$$
Let $c_j = b_j - \frac{1}{q-p}$, $c_j$ satisfies
$$c_j = \frac{q}{p}c_{j-1}$$
So
$$c_{j} = c_1\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{j-1}$$
We deduce
$$a_{j} = a_1 + \frac{j-1}{q-p} + c_1\sum_{k=0}^{j-2}\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{k}$$

with the convention
$$\sum_{k=n}^m A_k = 0,\text{ if }  m < n$$

Comment: Can you explain the last two steps? I don't follow. I understand the first three steps. How did you know to set $b_j$ and $c_j$ like that?

Comment: @clay for $b_j$, $p+q=1$ suggests to write $a_j = pa_j +qa_j$. For $c_j$, the equation $-pb_j +qb_{j-1}=1$ is affine not linear, so I searched $\alpha$ s.t. $c_j = b_j + \alpha$ satisfies $-pc_j + qc_{j-1} = 0$ and such $\alpha$ is $-\frac{1}{q-p}$. From $c_j = \frac{q}{p}c_{j-1}$ we prove by induction $c_j = \left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{j-1}c_1$: it is a geometric serie. From $b_j = a_{j+1} -a_j$ we deduce by induction $a_j = a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}b_j$ and $b_j = c_j + \frac{1}{q-p} = c_1\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{j-1} + \frac{1}{q-p}$